# LabelText of TextFormFeild on FocusedBorder in flutter not showing properly

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield

Hey I want the label text to below the top border `onFocusedBorder` of `TextFormField`, not go between the top border. How can I achieve that?
Hey I want the label text to below the top border `onFocusedBorder` of `TextFormField`, not go between the top border. How can I achieve that?

Below is the code of `TextFormFeild`

[image: Error]

Below is the code of `TextFormFeild`

```dart
Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.black),
       
 child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(33)),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: deviceSize
                .height, // Ignore this
            
child: TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black), // Text written color
              controller: _controller,
              cursorColor: Colors.black,

              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.black,
                labelText: "What are you looking for?",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                  fontSize: deviceSize.height * 0.4,
                ),

                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    size: deviceSize.height * 0.6,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Search functionality here
                  },
                ),

                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.filter_list,
                    size: deviceSize.height * 0.6,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => _controller.clear(),
                ),

              
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(33),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.brown,
                      width: 0.7,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace labelText and labelStyle with hintText and hintStyle.

The reason why it moves up is because labelText stays and it makes you type on a new line.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Spencer. I know about the hintText, I was just trying to find out how to change the position of the labelText. I don't want `labeltext` to go completely up. Just stay bit below the top border of `TextForFeild`

Comment: Ah ok if you still want the text to be there but not go outside of the box you will have to let the box expand. One way is to increase the maxLines property, or even set it to null if you want to let it make new lines forever.